# jQuery - run code after scripts are loaded

Tags: jquery, load

In my header I load scripts (I keep this scripts on my server, original links are added here just for you):

```
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
<script src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js">
```

Then on my footer I'm executing some code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(function(){
                $('.scroll-pane').load().jScrollPane();
            });
            numOfPics = $('#gallery-wraper img').size();
            widthOfAll = 0;
            $('#gallery-wraper img').each(function() {
                imgWidth = $(this).width() + 20;
                widthOfAll += imgWidth;
            }); // end of each
            $("#gallery-container").load().css("width",widthOfAll);

            galleryPosition = $(window).height() / 2 - 250;
            $("#gallery").css("margin-top", galleryPosition);
});// end of document.ready()
```

I want it yo display my images horizontally and put it inside jScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
But it displays my images horizontally after refresh only (or even after a few page refreshes in chrome). It looks like it tries to execute my code before page content is generated (its a wordpress theme) or before scroll libraries are loaded. What is wrong with my logic here? I'm using document.ready() so why it acts this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling it after the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
      $('.scroll-pane').load().jScrollPane();
  });
  function updateCSS() {
    numOfPics = $('#gallery-wraper img').size();
    widthOfAll = 0;
    $('#gallery-wraper img').each(function() {
        imgWidth = $(this).width() + 20;
        widthOfAll += imgWidth;
    }); // end of each
    $("#gallery-container").load().css("width",widthOfAll);

    galleryPosition = $(window).height() / 2 - 250;
    $("#gallery").css("margin-top", galleryPosition);
  }

  setTimeout('updateCSS()',100);
});// end of document.ready()
```

Comment: well... but what if someone has very slow connection. Like if he visit my page from a mobile phone without wi-fi. Then the timer may be to slow and he will see not what he should see...

Comment: If the connection is slow, it will still wait for the page to be fully loaded before the timer for 100ms starts.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. I've just had this bug on other computer with slower connection...

Comment: What happens on a slower connection? The code runs first before the page is loaded?

Comment: By the way Kyle's answer, `$(window).load` doesn't work for your site? Here is a good link that says when to use `load` or `ready` http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: Well, honestly I don't get it at all... It simply displays images vertically not horizontally and I get vertical scrollbar. But images container has good height (which is defined thru CSS). So it looks like jQuery is not loaded. Also, in what moment program sees my images width? After they are loaded or it first gets info about them? Thru CSS I also define images height and width: auto, maybe thats the problem when I get their width with jQuery.

Comment: Kyle's answers seems to be the best solution for me but when I use it it simply does the same bug - images are displayed vertically like my code is not loaded... I don't understand why cause all I change is `document.ready()` to `window.load()` and my code stays the same

Comment: I see your point there when using jQuery to get your image width. It's possible that your images are still loaded so jQuery might not get the correct width. I'll do some tests with that.

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle, I modified it a bit as `setTimeout('updateCSS()', 200)` is causing the error. Here's my edited link, http://jsfiddle.net/playerace/MrQzU/

Comment: so You changed it to 500, right? But it still makes timeout fire a bit later, so if I will have higher number of images it will break again. For example see this jsFiddle with a lot of images and timeout set to 500: http://jsfiddle.net/smogg/BC8TS/embedded/result/

Comment: @ace let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2288/discussion-between-smogg-and-ace)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is your issue or not, but try the $(window).load event instead of $(document).ready.  $(window).load executes after all libraries, images, frames, ect have loaded instead of after your HTML code loading (as your libraries and images may still be loading).

http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: well, I've read article You gave me, but when I'm trying to use window.load() instead jQuery doesn't load at all and my browser freezes for half a second...